# Pushing the limits with no JS single file multi page html file

Tags: html, css, accordion

I'm building a multi page single html file document.
That to be used with Android's default WebView. These means absolutely no JS.
(I wish I could use JS, but it doesn't supports it. I wish I could use 3rd party html viewer, but chance of the content of these file leaking is unacceptable.)

I have got it working using

```
      fieldset{
        display:none;
        &target{display: block;}
      }
```

These above CSS hides all the fieldsets, and it only shows the one that is targeted.

This basic makeup of the my html file

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <style>
      fieldset{
        display:none;
        &target{display: block;}
      }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="nav">
      <a href="#1">1</a> | <a href="#2">2</a> | <a href="#3">3</a>
    </div>

    <fieldset id="1">
      <a href="#1a">1a</a> | <a href="#1b">1b</a> | <a href="#1c">1c</a>
      <table>
        <tbody id="1a"></tbody>
        <tbody id="1b"></tbody>
        <tbody id="1c"></tbody>
      </table>
    </fieldset>
    <fieldset id="2"></fieldset>
    <fieldset id="3"></fieldset>
  </body>
</html>
```

However issue arises when i want it to also scroll down to targeted as well.

For example:
If browser targets #1 it will display fieldset id="1".
If browser targets #2 it will display fieldset id="2".
This is all good

, but the issue if the browsers targets #1a nothing gets displayed.
I could solve this by adding

```
      tbody{
        &target{display: block;}
      }
```

, but that is not what i want it to do.
What I want it to do is if #1a is targeted, display fieldset id="1", and scroll down to tbody id="1a".

I have brain fog I can't think How to solve this,and the Chatgpt is no use even if I'm telling her no JS, she inserts script in there every time.